# Do bacteria precipitate in static liquid culture media?

Tags: biofilms

We performed 36h biofilm cultures and would like to know if this time is enough to planktonic bacteria to precipitate. 
Since we observed biofilm formation one the surface of the microtiter plate. Were  biofilm bacteria derived from precipitation of suspended bacteria or rather replicated from some initial attached bacteria cells?

Specie: Haemophilus parasuis. A facultative anaerobe.

Comment: Maybe the question is irrelavant for the final outcome. The number of inoculated bacteria cells was so small that would not influence the numbers of biofilm bacterial cells observed, almost sure all were derived form initial attached cells.

Comment: You didn't specify the species, but I have left *E. coli* transformations (in 500µl of SOC) overnight due to rushing/forgetting to dispose of them after the transformation, and they were precipitated in the morning.

Comment: yup, e.coli for mini preps can precipitate pretty quickly (overnight growth in 3 mL culture). I notice clearing of media (sort of supernatant) after maybe 12-24hr. But other species might behave differently